# Хранение ссылок на документы и их обработка

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, xmlparser

Для обновления приложения мне понадобилось хранить ссылки на текстовые документы из папки assets. 
Если идти от корня папки, то структура имеет вид: язык/ категория/ подкатегория/ группа/ файлы от 2 до 7.

Возникла мысль хранить все в xml файле и парсить это все с последующей записью в sqlite, а потом искать в базе данных нужную группу и открывать текстовые документы.
Читать текстовые файлы и выводить уже могу, код написан, но не могу придумать правильную структуру для xml документа, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было одинаково извлечь как 2 ссылки, так и 6. Парсер под это дело подобрать не могу.

Пример ссылки на файл:

assets/ru/1.category/1.subcategory/group/file.1.txt

assets/ru/1.category/1.subcategory/group/file.2.txt

assets/ru/1.category/4.subcategory/group/file.1.txt

Comment: Ссылки в json засовывай, быстей чем XML вроде...

Comment: можно базу sqlite прямо в приложении хранить

Comment: Я в бд и так буду хранить, но до этого туда их нужно записать, поэтому и пошел пл пути xml.

Comment: @web_alex, вместо xml в ассеты можно положить готовую, заранее сформированную базу.  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @lsillarionov, спасибо! Завтра попробую заюзать.
А в каком виде мне хранить данные ? 
Делать две записи в БД, чтобы сохранить две ссылки на файлы или добавить столбцов еще ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на мой вопрос:

- **"парсер":**

  ```
  Context context;

  AssetManager mgr;

  public LinksClass(Context context) throws XmlPullParserException {
      Log.v(LOG_TAG, "start LinksClass");
      mgr = context.getResources().getAssets();
      this.context = context;
      try {
          XmlPullParser parser = this.context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.appfiles);
          while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("dir")) {
                  // create link
                  String deviceLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
                  String link = deviceLang + "/" +
                  /*category*/ parser.getAttributeValue(0) + "/"
                  /*group*/  + parser.getAttributeValue(1) + "/"
                  /*dir*/    + parser.getAttributeValue(2);
                      Log.v(LOG_TAG, "link: " + link);
                  String dir = parser.getAttributeValue(2);
                  getListFiles(link);
                  String name = getCorrectName(dir);
              }
              parser.next();
          }
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
          Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка при загрузке XML-документа: " + t.toString());
      }
  }
  ```
- **структура xml файла**

  `<struct>
  <dir lang = "ru" category = "1.cat" group = "1.group" dir = "set" />
  <dir lang = "ru" category = "1.cat" group = "1.group" dir = "get" />
  <!-- и так далее -->
  </struct>`

В итоге при помощи `parser.getAttributeValue(НОМЕР_АТРИБУТА)` мы можем сформировать ссылку на каждый каталог в `assets`, добавив слэш и текущий язык на гаджете.

Пример ссылки: `1/ru/1.cat/1.group/set`. 
(Да, структура директорий изменена. Это произошло в процессе проектирования.)

**ПОМНИТЕ**, что **НЕ НУЖНО** добавлять слэш `/` до и после нашей ссылки.

- **пару слов об sqlite**

Так как запись в Базу данных(БД) sqlite не являлась ключевым вопросом, то и раскрывать этот вопрос не стоит. Вы, мой дорогой читатель, сможете легко найти вопрос о CRUD (**C**reate-**R**ead-**U**pdate-**D**elete) в сети Интернет. 
Но кратко опишу свои действия, если кому-то понадобится сам ход решение вопроса:

1. записать в БД данные в каждую колонку (любым из вариантов):

   1.1. Запись ссылки в раздельном виде

   Колонки таблицы БД: `_id | name | lang | category | group | dir`

   1.2. Запись ссылки целиком

   Колонки таблицы БД: `_id | name | link`
2. организовать поиск в колонке `name`.

Comment: Я так и не понял, зачем понадобилось сперва вручную засунуть строки в xml, а потом героически их парсить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, для будущей организации поиска информации в приложении, которое частично работает на текстовых файлах.

Comment: То есть в дальнейшем информация меняется и дополняется. Тогда согласен. Принято.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, верно)))